# dual svm square hinge loss

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y_1,\dots,y_n\in \{-1,1\}$, $\lambda \ge 0$
and $K$ be the invertible Gram matrix $K=(x_i\cdot x_j)_{ij}$.

Consider
$$
(P) \qquad \qquad \min_{a\in \mathbb{R}^n} \lambda a^\intercal Ka + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \max(0,1-y_i(Ka)_i)^2 
$$

I want to compute the dual problem of $(P)$, in particular I want to recover the formulation given https://youtu.be/glDhR4Iq1sE?t=3098 :
$$
(D) \qquad \qquad \min_{a\in \mathbb{R}^n} 2a^\intercal y -a^\intercal (K+n\lambda I)a\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 0\le y_i a_i,\ i=1,\dots n
$$

---

We can observe that the function $u\mapsto \max(0,1-u)^2$ is differentiable and its derivative is $u\mapsto 2(1-u)\chi_{]-\infty,1]}(u)$ where $\chi_{]-\infty,1]}$ is the indicator function of $]-\infty,1]$.

The problem $(P)$ can be rewritten :
$$
(P) \qquad \qquad \min_{a\in \mathbb{R}^n} \lambda a^\intercal Ka + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (1-y_i(Ka)_i)^2 \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 1\ge y_i (Ka)_i,\ i=1,\dots n
$$
and the Lagrangian function is
$$
L(a,\nu)= \lambda a^\intercal Ka+\frac{1}{n}\|\mathbf{1}-D_y Ka\|_2^2
-\nu^\intercal\mathbf{1}  + \nu^\intercal D_yKa\\
= 1 -\frac{2}{n} y^\intercal Ka +  \frac{1}{n}a^\intercal K (D_y^2 K + n\lambda I)a -\nu^\intercal\mathbf{1}  + \nu^\intercal D_yKa
$$
with $\mathbf{1}=(1,\dots,1)^\intercal$ and $D_y=diag(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ (diagonal matrix).

Then I compute the dual function $g(\nu)=\inf_a L(a,\nu)$ and differentiating $L$ with repect to $a$ leads to

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=\frac{2}{n} K(D_y^2K+ \lambda n I)a - \frac{2}{n}K y + KD_y\nu
$$
and from $\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=0$ we get
$$
(D_y^2K+ \lambda n I)a =  y - \frac{n}{2}D_y\nu
$$

Using this equality to eliminate $a$ in $L$, I obtain
$$
L(a,\nu)_{\mid \partial_aL=0}
= 1 -\frac{1}{n} y^\intercal Ka + \frac{1}{2}\nu^\intercal D_yKa
 -\nu^\intercal\mathbf{1}  
$$

but I cannot recover the dual problem $(D)$.

Any insight how to recover this dual ?